# Passing data from partial view to another view

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

This is the partialView

```
@model IEnumerable<NeoCBSModel.MembersList>
<div id="membersModal">
<h4>Members List</h4>

<table class="table table-responsive dataTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Saving Ac No</th>
            <th>Member Name</th>
            <th>Saving Product</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td><a id="select" href="#" onclick="closeModal();">Select</a></td>
                <td>@item.saving_account_no</td>
                <td>@item.memberName</td>
                <td>@item.product_name</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>

</table>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  function closeModal() {
    $("#membersModal").hide();
}

$(".dataTable").DataTable();
```

I am showing the above partialView as a modal dialog. The following code-block is for another view. I did it the following way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#memberName').focusin(function () {
    //$('#membermodal').modal('show');
    _dialog = $("#members").dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        position: { my: "center", at: "top+100", of: window },
        width: 800,
        resizable: false,
        modal: true,
        open: function () {
            $(this).load('@Url.Action("GetMemberList","SavingTranscation")');
        },
        close: function () {
            closeModal("#members");
        }
    });
})
</script>
```

After this, it shows a close button above the modal. I just want to get rid of it. and the "select" link must send `@item.saving_account_no` to the parent view.

Comment: Where is `$("#members")`?

Comment: $("#members") is in the parent view.


    <div id="members"></div>

it is used in displaying the partialView as modal dialog.

Comment: @AnayaUpadhyay that means you've got a dependency in your partial view on the parent view. In which case, why bother making it a partial if it's not fully re-usable?

Comment: And what do you mean by "send it to the parent view"? Be more specific please. Should it get sent to the server and processed. Or just displayed in the client UI with no reference to the server? Be clear about what the end result is

Comment: @ADyson i want it as a partialView because it is used in other views also.

Sorry, if you got confused. I just want the value displayed in the textbox of the parent view.

Comment: @AnayaUpadhyay I understand you want to re-use it elsewhere, but what I'm saying is by making a JS reference to the parent page you're creating a dependency on the parent, which is not good encapsulation if you want a genuinely re-usable view. When you come to another page, you have to create exactly the same "members" element in that parent in order for the partial to work properly. It's a small thing in this specific case, but the principle is to avoid doing that sort of thing in case it causes bigger problems to untangle.

Comment: @AnayaUpadhyay again if you want it genuinely re-usable, in order to populate your textbox I would emit a custom JS event containing the value, and have the parent page listen for that event and populate the textbox. That way the view does not need to know the exact name of the textbox, and so you don't create another dependency. See here https://learn.jquery.com/events/introduction-to-custom-events/